# Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: column "id" is of type bigint but expression is of type text

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I want to create a SQL script which generates test data using Liquibase. I tried this:

***Entity:***

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
public class Tasks implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title", length = 100)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "meta_title", length = 100)
    private String metaTitle;

    @Column(name = "business_name", length = 100)
    private String businessName;
  ......
}
```

SQL Script:

```
INSERT into tasks SELECT
    ('Business name ' || generate_series(1,355)) AS business_name,
    (select NOW() + (random() * (NOW() + '90 days' - NOW())) + '30 days') AS created_at,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS meta_title,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS status,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS title,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS task_type,
    (select NOW() + (random() * (NOW() + '90 days' - NOW())) + '30 days') AS updated_at;
```

Error:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/changelog/changes/ch_0001/data/data.yaml::1::test:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: column "id" is of type bigint but expression is of type text
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 42 [Failed SQL: (0) INSERT into tasks SELECT
    ('Business name ' || generate_series(1,355)) AS business_name,
    (select NOW() + (random() * (NOW() + '90 days' - NOW())) + '30 days') AS created_at,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS meta_title,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS status,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS title,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS task_type,
    (select NOW() + (random() * (NOW() + '90 days' - NOW())) + '30 days') AS updated_at]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:659)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:53)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:97)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:201)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:178)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:368)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:316)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: column "id" is of type bigint but expression is of type text
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 42 [Failed SQL: (0) INSERT into tasks SELECT
    ('Business name ' || generate_series(1,355)) AS business_name,
    (select NOW() + (random() * (NOW() + '90 days' - NOW())) + '30 days') AS created_at,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS meta_title,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS status,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS title,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS task_type,
    (select NOW() + (random() * (NOW() + '90 days' - NOW())) + '30 days') AS updated_at]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:430)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:87)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:159)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1276)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1258)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:622)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "id" is of type bigint but expression is of type text
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 42
```

I want Postgress to auto-generate database table id and I only to insert new data.
Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the target columns in the INSERT statement. In fact doing so is good coding practice and should **always** be done, not just when you get an error. The matching between the target table columns and the SELECT columns is done by position not by name.

```
INSERT into tasks (business_name, created_at, meta_title, status, title, ask_type, updated_at)
SELECT
    'Business name ' || id AS business_name,
    (NOW() + (random() * (NOW() + '90 days' - NOW())) + '30 days') AS created_at,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS meta_title,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS status,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS title,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS task_type,
    (NOW() + (random() * (NOW() + '90 days' - NOW())) + '30 days') AS updated_at
FROM generate_series(1,355) as g(id)
```

As a side note:

There is no need to use `SELECT` when using the `now()` function (you are not doing that for `md5()` or `random()` either). And in general it's better to put set returning functions into the `FROM` clause.